# find missing value which are present in sheet 1 but not in sheet 2

Tags: excel, vba

I have written a sample code which compare two sheets and highlight different if any value in sheet1 for col1  is not find in sheet2 for col2

I want to expand this code to whole sheet. So that any value  which is not present in Sheet 2 is highlighted in sheet 1.

How can I do that? I tried to increase range by A:Z but it gave me error

```
Sub CompareAndHighlight()

Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, i As Integer, j As Integer
Dim isMatch As Boolean

For i = 2 To Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    isMatch = False
    Set rng1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i)
    For j = 1 To Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng2 = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A:B" & j)
        If StrComp(Trim(rng1.Text), Trim(rng2.Text), vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            isMatch = True
            Exit For
        End If
        Set rng2 = Nothing
    Next j

    If Not isMatch Then
        rng1.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    End If
    Set rng1 = Nothing
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: I am not getting any error for this code but when I try to include by "A:B" syntax I get error

Comment: I already did makes changes to code.

Comment: None of this is VBScript, two people answering but neither of you can sort the tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub CompareAndHighlight()

Dim xRange As Range, yRange As Range
Dim xCell As Range, yCell As Range
Dim Found As Range

Dim wsX As Worksheet: Set wsX = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim wsY As Worksheet: Set wsY = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

LR1 = wsX.Range("A" & wsX.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
LR2 = wsY.Range("B" & wsY.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Set xRange = wsX.Range("A1:A" & LR1)
Set yRange = wsY.Range("B1:B" & LR2)

For Each xCell In xRange

    Set Found = yRange.Find(xCell.Value)

    If Found Is Nothing Then
        xCell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    End If

    Set Found = Nothing

Next xCell

End Sub
```

Comment: ok u have "B" in second sheet and I have "A". I changed it . thank you very much and I give you  big kiss. Cheers

Comment: I'd be careful if there are values below the last cell in column A in other columns. With this approach LR1 = wsX.Range("A" & wsX.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row you may left them without being compared.

Comment: This finds the last row from the bottom @RicardoDiaz so there cannot be anything else beneath..

Comment: @urdearboy In other columns. zee said that the objective is to look in the whole sheet.

Comment: Oh - well yes. Adjust the LR1 to use the column that is most likely to indicate the end of your range. I used Column A because that is already what Op was using @RicardoDiaz. Can’t anticipate every issue

Comment: @urdearboy you're right. In my case, II used "UsedRange" in my solution to leave that issue to Excel

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub CompareAndHighlight()

    ' Declare object variables
    Dim originalRange As Range
    Dim compareToSheet As Worksheet
    Dim cellRange As Range

    ' Declare other variables
    Dim originalSheetName As String
    Dim compareSheetName As String

    ' >>> Customize
    originalSheetName = "Sheet1"
    compareSheetName = "Sheet2"

    ' Initiate objects
    Set originalRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(originalSheetName).UsedRange
    Set compareToSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(compareSheetName)


    ' Loop through used cells in first sheet
    For Each cellRange In originalRange

        If StrComp(cellRange.Value, compareToSheet.Range(cellRange.Address).Value, vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
            cellRange.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        End If

    Next

End Sub
```